# What are the ways of using Stack Overflow effectively without distributing reputation across different communities?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I have been contributing to Stack Overflow, DBA, [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), and other communities. I thought my contribution across platform will earn me reputation on Stack Overflow as a whole. It seems that my contribution to each community is counted separately.
How do I effectively contribute to community while earning reputation?

Which is the better approach for earning reputation, earning through single community or spread out answers in communities related to areas of expertise?

Comment: Sorry, you actually only need 200 rep in one site. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus).

Comment: It doesn't sound like this question is asking about the 100 rep association bonus, but rather forming a "rep pool" for all sites in the Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that was exactly my intention behind asking this question.

Answer (score 22):

The different sites are *completely different communities*, with some natural variation in their policies and expectations. This is why the reputation earned does not transfer.

Earning privileges on one site means that you have invested a lot of time in that site and can reasonably be taken to imply that you are familiar with its policies and expectations. That's not necessarily the case for other sites on the network. As a case in point, [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) has some natural overlap with Stack Overflow in its scope, but it has very different standards for questions than Stack Overflow does. Same for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), and other sites.

I was elected as a moderator on Stack Overflow, implying two things: (1) that I'm pretty familiar with the standards for how our site operates, what is on-topic, etc., and (2) that the community *generally* trusts my judgment in enforcing those policies. I am not, however, an expert on how they do things over on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com). In fact, I've never even participated on that site. As such, I don't think that community wants me coming in and doing moderator-y stuff—not until I've earned those privileges on that site, from that community.

That said, we recognize that all Stack Exchange sites have some fundamental commonalities. This is why, [once you've earned 200 reputation on one site, you are automatically given 100 reputation on any new site that you join](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus). This is called an "association bonus", and it effectively means that your accounts on new sites will start with 101 reputation, giving you the ability to do things like upvote and post comments, the rules for which are essentially the same on all sites.

Some overlap in scope, especially on technical sites, is natural and not cause for alarm. For example, plenty of questions about database administration are on-topic for Stack Overflow—in particular, those related to programming. If you choose to ask them here instead of on DBA, that's fine. Then, you'll be participating on Stack Overflow, expanding our knowledge base, and earning reputation here. Just because another site exists with an overlapping scope does not mean that the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -3):

To summarize Cody's response, if you're looking to build up reputation specifically, use Stack Overflow for as many questions/answers as possible since most DB and Unix questions will be appropriate here with the correct tag(s).

Comment: if you want to summarize some one's answer, please write it as a COMMENT, not a answer